# I'm installing Chutney to try to emulate a private TOR network

Tags: network-configuration, tor-network

My goal is to create a private Tor network in order to first de-anonymize a user and then develop a patch to address the issue. Currently, I have decided to create the Tor network using Chutney. Everything is working correctly, and I have managed to build and start a "basic" network as follows:

```
network-status-version 3
vote-status consensus
consensus-method 33
valid-after 2023-10-31 10:23:40
fresh-until 2023-10-31 10:24:00
valid-until 2023-10-31 10:24:20
voting-delay 4 4
client-versions 
server-versions 
known-flags Authority Exit Fast Guard HSDir NoEdConsensus Running Stable StaleDesc Sybil V2Dir Valid
recommended-client-protocols Cons=2 Desc=2 DirCache=2 HSDir=2 HSIntro=4 HSRend=2 Link=4-5 Microdesc=2 Relay=2
recommended-relay-protocols Cons=2 Desc=2 DirCache=2 HSDir=2 HSIntro=4 HSRend=2 Link=4-5 LinkAuth=3 Microdesc=2 Relay=2
required-client-protocols Cons=2 Desc=2 Link=4 Microdesc=2 Relay=2
required-relay-protocols Cons=2 Desc=2 DirCache=2 HSDir=2 HSIntro=4 HSRend=2 Link=4-5 LinkAuth=3 Microdesc=2 Relay=2
params AuthDirMaxServersPerAddr=0 cc_alg=2
shared-rand-previous-value 3 rUcn/IT4nhqv5eCzCsDBVGVzQRdFkOR/UajC3JixiYM=
shared-rand-current-value 3 C3gHLw06tYDXyBeubziJegbUCf43YMpbGOi7y3YXDps=
dir-source test000a 0A8501C1768E76F416F61C28DF1049F40EA3033C 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 7000 5000
contact auth0@test.test
vote-digest C3CD210E2FCAAD65471871FD5B37FE60FB1AE25E
dir-source test001a 2094F53F2D6A3B3628C074E54EF0FCE812F97699 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 7001 5001
contact auth1@test.test
vote-digest 6C32539D17ED084A170F5F690392DE6DB983851C
dir-source test002a 92A77533CD5C41C22B5113303F4AC719B94EA0A8 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 7002 5002
contact auth2@test.test
vote-digest 697070F2E5264238D5C59391F330B34340C1E1E0
r test005r F6VWC0G33NIDQzU1nCKRnaD0/q8 n+GIcD89B/BUjn7Cy/JTYFz8/aE 2023-10-31 09:22:31 127.0.0.1 5005 0
s Exit Fast Guard HSDir Running Stable V2Dir Valid
v Tor 0.4.8.7
pr Conflux=1 Cons=1-2 Desc=1-2 DirCache=2 FlowCtrl=1-2 HSDir=2 HSIntro=4-5 HSRend=1-2 Link=1-5 LinkAuth=1,3 Microdesc=1-2 Padding=2 Relay=1-4
w Bandwidth=71 Unmeasured=1
p accept 1-65535
r test002a XK1ki9B89y2qO7ecWtvbvScga6A 80zBwz5yMcvrx+tsbYBwIGq6unc 2023-10-31 09:55:21 127.0.0.1 5002 7002
s Authority Exit Fast Guard HSDir Running Stable V2Dir Valid
v Tor 0.4.8.7
pr Conflux=1 Cons=1-2 Desc=1-2 DirCache=2 FlowCtrl=1-2 HSDir=2 HSIntro=4-5 HSRend=1-2 Link=1-5 LinkAuth=1,3 Microdesc=1-2 Padding=2 Relay=1-4
w Bandwidth=187 Unmeasured=1
p reject 1-65535
r test003r fipHaZCXkRHJIxZBOsyX2WqFwCg +GLjGaNBgO8ftALbiuAEzDJQHRk 2023-10-31 09:22:31 127.0.0.1 5003 0
s Exit Fast Guard HSDir Running Stable V2Dir Valid
v Tor 0.4.8.7
pr Conflux=1 Cons=1-2 Desc=1-2 DirCache=2 FlowCtrl=1-2 HSDir=2 HSIntro=4-5 HSRend=1-2 Link=1-5 LinkAuth=1,3 Microdesc=1-2 Padding=2 Relay=1-4
w Bandwidth=106 Unmeasured=1
p accept 1-65535
r test001a h7XwPg2pOTJcBhri3trz70CucK0 QQcHys13REdNj91vofR1t69pHow 2023-10-31 09:55:21 127.0.0.1 5001 7001
s Authority Exit Fast Guard HSDir Running Stable V2Dir Valid
v Tor 0.4.8.7
pr Conflux=1 Cons=1-2 Desc=1-2 DirCache=2 FlowCtrl=1-2 HSDir=2 HSIntro=4-5 HSRend=1-2 Link=1-5 LinkAuth=1,3 Microdesc=1-2 Padding=2 Relay=1-4
w Bandwidth=120 Unmeasured=1
p reject 1-65535
r test006r xniMQd2ScOo/IduuY2q9greMzwA eFgky8YnEeZdM6dRy0qITHGySU0 2023-10-30 18:10:53 127.0.0.1 5006 0
s Exit Fast Guard HSDir Running Stable V2Dir Valid
v Tor 0.4.8.7
pr Conflux=1 Cons=1-2 Desc=1-2 DirCache=2 FlowCtrl=1-2 HSDir=2 HSIntro=4-5 HSRend=1-2 Link=1-5 LinkAuth=1,3 Microdesc=1-2 Padding=2 Relay=1-4
w Bandwidth=56 Unmeasured=1
p accept 1-65535
r test007r yTvBIhZ7ytGqN88g/afj2tKbQAw 3vgPnqwCHqDeCD91/q5p9Q0j6CY 2023-10-30 18:09:53 127.0.0.1 5007 0
s Exit Fast Guard HSDir Running Stable V2Dir Valid
v Tor 0.4.8.7
pr Conflux=1 Cons=1-2 Desc=1-2 DirCache=2 FlowCtrl=1-2 HSDir=2 HSIntro=4-5 HSRend=1-2 Link=1-5 LinkAuth=1,3 Microdesc=1-2 Padding=2 Relay=1-4
w Bandwidth=55 Unmeasured=1
p accept 1-65535
r test000a 1I5Rn/gdwFUa1mqqqoHO6IoiZvA vMfHfrDhomTYVy0SOfnA5OHlOyw 2023-10-31 09:55:22 127.0.0.1 5000 7000
s Authority Exit Fast Guard HSDir Running V2Dir Valid
v Tor 0.4.8.7
pr Conflux=1 Cons=1-2 Desc=1-2 DirCache=2 FlowCtrl=1-2 HSDir=2 HSIntro=4-5 HSRend=1-2 Link=1-5 LinkAuth=1,3 Microdesc=1-2 Padding=2 Relay=1-4
w Bandwidth=149 Unmeasured=1
p reject 1-65535
r test004r 4DbmTov/anv0146KA884JQ30Nxc zr97lvG2T56NTS2J5nt098FhtrY 2023-10-31 09:22:31 127.0.0.1 5004 0
s Exit Fast Guard HSDir Running Stable V2Dir Valid
v Tor 0.4.8.7
pr Conflux=1 Cons=1-2 Desc=1-2 DirCache=2 FlowCtrl=1-2 HSDir=2 HSIntro=4-5 HSRend=1-2 Link=1-5 LinkAuth=1,3 Microdesc=1-2 Padding=2 Relay=1-4
w Bandwidth=55 Unmeasured=1
p accept 1-65535
directory-footer
bandwidth-weights Wbd=3333 Wbe=0 Wbg=0 Wbm=10000 Wdb=10000 Web=10000 Wed=3333 Wee=10000 Weg=3333 Wem=10000 Wgb=10000 Wgd=3333 Wgg=10000 Wgm=10000 Wmb=10000 Wmd=3333 Wme=0 Wmg=0 Wmm=10000
directory-signature 0A8501C1768E76F416F61C28DF1049F40EA3033C A2E9F25E2526A060677A2DB545067D699F4AAC50
```

Now, my question is: Is it possible to impersonate a user and send a packet through the network that can be sniffed both at the entry node and the exit node using Wireshark?